# Multiple webviews in wp8?

Tags: c#, javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8

How do you embed a webview that can open other webviews that you can easily switch between into a PhoneGap application for Windows Phone 8? I can't find any resources on how to embed multiple webviews into a windows 8 mobile app. I'm really asking for any kind of guidance that could help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone does not support multiple `WebBrowser` controls on a single page. You'll need to use multiple pages if you need multiple embedded browser controls or change the contents of a single embedded control.

Without knowing what you're trying to achieve it's hard to know what the best suitable approach could be for you.

Comment: I'm trying to make an app that opens a webpage with links to a bunch of individual widgets. I would like it so that when a link to one is clicked, it opens in a new page. Later, i would like to have a dropdown menu that would enable me to switch between all the available open webpages.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [ChildBrowser plugin](https://github.com/sgrebnov/incubator-cordova-wp8/tree/master/plugins/www/plugins/ChildBrowser) which allows you to open a new browser window and even has events to capture responses from the spawned child window. This is the most closest thing in PhoneGap you are looking for.